# Chicago MOS for Bibliographic References - BibMe and CiteThisforMe seem to disagree

Tags: citations

Which of these (if either) is the correct method of citing a journal article using the Chicago Manual of Style? Each of these were entered using the same article.

**This one was generated by CiteThisforMe:**

Arsenault, A., and G. Cowan. 2008. "Moving From Monologue To Dialogue To Collaboration: The Three Layers Of Public Diplomacy". *The ANNALS Of The American Academy Of Political And Social Science* 616 (1): 10-30. doi:10.1177/0002716207311863.

**This one was generated by BibMe:**

Arsenault, A., and G. Cowan. "Moving from Monologue to Dialogue to Collaboration: The Three Layers of Public Diplomacy." T*he ANNALS of the American Academy of Political and Social Science* 616, no. 1 (2008): 10-30. doi:10.1177/0002716207311863.